# Send email on ssh login

Tags: bash, email, ssh

I want to make sure everytime someone is login into my server I receive an email saying:

> ALERT Shell Access on: Tue Jun 16 11:04:10 CDT 2009 user123 pts/0
>   2009-06-16 11:04

So I put this code:

```
echo 'ALERT Shell Access on:' `date` `who` | mail -s "Alert: Root Access from `who | cut -d"(" -f2 | cut -d")" -f1`" example@example.com
```

in the `.bashrc`.

Why I don't receive any emails?

Thank you for your help, J

Comment: Did you reload ~/.bashrc via `source ~/.bashrc` ? and did you try to logout and login again?

Comment: Are you getting any messages in /var/log/messages or anything like that?  Does that user/environment know where mail is?

Comment: Yes I logged out completely, and logged back in. I also tried source ~/.bashrc but no success

Comment: @CtrlDot when I use the mail command in the shell, I get the email. I don't see anything in /var/log/mail.log or /var/log/message

Comment: @alreal, i tried again but didn't work. It only worked when I source the .bashrc which is not really my goal here.

Comment: [Good answer on askunbuntu.com for ubuntu users and maybe others...][1]


  [1]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/179889/how-do-i-set-up-an-email-alert-when-a-ssh-login-is-successful

Answer (score 11, accepted):

.bashrc is executed when bash is run as a interactive non-login shell, which is not the case when you ssh.
Add the same code in .bash_profile which should be run when the shell is a login shell

Note: Many distributions source .bashrc from .bash_profile, I may be wrong and the issue may not be about .bashrc / .bash_profile

Comment: it works but I lost all my colors theme etc... when I remove the .bash_profile everything is back to normal

Comment: What distribution do you use ?

Comment: One Linux CentOS 5 and One Ubuntu Server 10.04

Comment: for Ubuntu, the file is .profile in your home directory (if you create .bash_profile, the .profile is not read)

Comment: But for both distribution, the profile sources the bashrc by default. Can you post the content of your .profile and .bash_profile ?

Comment: You need to source .profile from .bash_profile, because bash no longer reads .profile once .bash_profile exists.

Comment: @Tech4Wilco add the details like your distribution editing your post please, more info on the basic question is the best for further readings and readers, thx

Answer (score 2):

Add into `/etc/ssh/sshrc`

```
ip=`echo $SSH_CONNECTION | cut -d " " -f 1`

logger -t ssh-wrapper $USER login from $ip
msg="User $USER just logged in from $ip"
echo $msg|mail -s $msg root
```